# Navigate to another route from a service

Tags: nativescript

I have service that intercepts all my Http requests so I can check if the user's token is valid or not. When a Http response is 401, I want the current user to be logged out of the application:

```
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Request, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Config } from './shared/config'
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'

@Injectable() 
export class RequestInterceptorService extends Http {
    private config: Config = new Config()

    constructor(
        backend: ConnectionBackend, 
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions, 
        private router: Router,
        private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
    ) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions)
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options))
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                this.logout()
                return Observable.empty()
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err)
            }
        })
    }

    logout() {
        this.config.clear()

        this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/signin"], {
            clearHistory: true
        })
    }
}
```

My issue is that router or routerExtensions are always undefined, so I can't really redirect the user to any other path at all using this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution. It was just a mater of understanding all of what I was doing.

I created a `RequestInterceptor` service that extends `Http` module. It includes a interceptor that checks if the status code is equal to 401. In order to make it compatible with my project, I decided to provide it as  custom implementation of `Http`. The following code on my @NgModule does just that:

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: Http,
        useClass: RequestInterceptorService
    }
]
```

But the thing `RequestInterceptorService` does not have access to `Http` dependencies: `ConnectionBackend` and `RequestOptions`, so I had to inject them using the `deps` property, which is an array where I can identify an array of dependencies that will get injected. In my case, I need to inject not only the dependencies that `Http` requires (`XHRBackend`, `RequestOptions`), but also the one that my service will use: `RouterExtensions`.

My `providers` declaration looks like this:

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: Http,
        useClass: RequestInterceptorService,
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, RouterExtensions]
    }
]
```

After doing this, I was able to successfully redirect a user to the login page when a 401 status code is returned from any request.